# How to check if NSURL contains NSString null?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, null, nsurl

I use the following code to get a NSString from a NSDictionary and then cast it into NSUrl:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.item objectForKey:@"website"]];
```

The NSDictionary `self.item` comes from a web server and it's correctly filled using JSON data. All the other objects inside the NSDictionary work perfectly fine.

But sometimes the web server passes a website url with the text "null" because the object has no website filled in. From debugging i learned that the NSURL object can contain a url with the text "null". But how do i prevent this, or how can i write an if statement that checks this?

I tried the following:

```
NSString * niks = [eventUrl absoluteString];
if(niks == @"null")
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Event" message:@"Event heeft geen website" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Oke" otherButtonTitles:@"Oke", nil];
    [message show];
}
else
{
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:eventUrl]];
    NSLog(@"%@",eventUrl);
}
```

But this doesn't work, it always passes the url directly to the webview. Can someone set me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison;

```
if(niks == @"null")
```

only compares if the pointers are equal (i.e. if the two are the same string object instance). Since one is a constant and the other is created dynamically from JSON fetched from the server, it's very unlikely.

To compare the *content* of two strings, you should instead do;

```
if([niks isEqualToString:@"null"])
```

For the link thirsty, [here is the [NSString isEqualToString:] documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:).

Answer (score 1):

To do string comparison, you need to do [niks isEqualToString:@"null"], that's why the first condition is broken.
You can also use [niks RangeOfString:@"null"];

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this:

```
id str = [self.item objectForKey:@"website"];
if([str isMemberOfClass[NSNull class]]) { 
    ... its null
}
```

The JSON convertors all change null to a NSNull object (in my experience).

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear of my memory, but I encountered a situation where `[NSDictionary objectForKey:]` actually returned `NSNull` class instance instead of "null" string.

If this is the case, you can check the class of `[self.item objectForKey:@"website"]` by using `isKindOfClass` method.